# Everyone who sees this puzzle has at least one of me

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> It's time to play a game, are you ready to Play?
> A place? I am the same. I don't change day to Day.
>
> Do you know who I am, managed by Registries?
> Even if I'm used to scam, your identity they Seize.
>
> Someone who knows me may be able to change what I am, even when you cannot.

What am I?

Comment: But the dynamic ones change every day? Maybe you've only had more expensive plans or live in less populated areas. Where I'm from it's a premium service for extra monthly pay to have it never change day to day. Kinda flaws the riddle a little.

Comment: Most people keep static, which is why I included the last line. Or at least, as far as I know in the USA, most people keep static. I should have done more research on this one. sorry

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you've already told us:

> IP ADDRESS

It's time to play a game, are you ready to Play?
A place? I am the same. I don't change day to Day.

> IPs are constant and stay to your location

Do you know who I am, managed by Registries?

Even if I'm used to scam, your identity they Seize.

> They're managed by registries, and are crucial for identity theft

Someone who knows me may be able to change what I am, even when you cannot.

> Those who are experienced with IPs can certainly do a lot of damage

But most importantly

> The first and last letter of each sentence spell out an acrostic: **IP ADDRESS**

And as for the title

> Everyone viewing this must have an IP

Comment: Oh i think you are right. Nice catch with that acrostic

Comment: I think El-Guest barely beat you to the answer, but great job.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know Actually, the timestamp shows Simon ahead by 4 seconds (14:41:37Z to 14:41:41Z).  You can mouse over the "answered x minutes ago" to see the timestamp.

Comment: @hagfy, Thanks! El-Guest answers a lot of my questions anyway. I'll give you the accepted answer Simon.

Comment: @Simon close race! Great answer :)

Answer (score 10):

Are you

> an IP address?

It's time to play a game, are you ready to Play?
A place? I am the same. I don't change day to Day.

> Your IP address doesn't change day to day

Do you know who I am, managed by Registries?
Even if I'm used to scam, your identity they Seize.

> It is managed by a central registry, and hackers mimicking your IP address can steal your online identity

Someone who knows me may be able to change what I am, even when you cannot.

> Computer people and registry officials might be able to change IP addresses, even if we can't

The title

> refers to the fact that everyone with a computer has an IP address

The secret hint

> every capital letter at the beginning and ending of lines spells IP ADDRESS

Comment: This would work, but you can change your ip address yourself.

Comment: That's it. By the way, you can find the answer in the puzzle. I wouldn't call it acrostic, but see if you can find it!

Comment: IP Address as each capital letter in the poem spells it out.

Comment: But my DHCP lease is only a few hours.

Answer (score 3):

Could you be a :

> Social Security Number?

A place? I am the same. I don't change day to Day.

> Not sure about the "Place", but SSN does not change (usually)

Do you know who I am, managed by Registries?

> The Registry of Motor Vehicles, or something by that name depending on where you live, needs your SSN to give you a license.

Even if I'm used to scam, your identity they Seize.

> Identity theft goes hand in hand with SSN

Someone who knows me may be able to change what I am, even when you cannot.

> If your identity is stolen, you can get your SSN changed, but you cannot change it yourself.

Comment: It's not this, but this is a great guess.

Comment: Why should everyone who sees this puzzle have at least one social security number?

Comment: Okay, perhaps not strictly a SSN, but some National Identification Number.

Comment: This was my guess too. You beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

> IP Address as each capital letter in the poem spells it out.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! When answering questions, please ensure to use spoiler tags >! in order to hide your answer. Also, please check in future to ensure you're not duplicating previous answers (as both myself and Simon answered this question correctly three hours ago).

Comment: Aw man, nice one! I kept looking up things for rot13(CQEF), but ignored the rot13(svefg yrggref bs rnpu yvar)!